# Sharepoint File Search and Copy

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I need to develop a function in java using the microsoft graph api, that would search for a file with a specific name, and copy it to a another destination.

I am able to search and find the file, but i am getting a error of itemNotFound when i try to do the copy.

To clarify the user i am using to search has universal access, and the file usually is in the drive of another user.
The destination is a backup site for these files.

Here is my code

```
private static String copyFile(String fileName, String destinationPath){

        try {
            long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authTokenProvider).buildClient();

        LinkedList<SearchRequest> requestsList = new LinkedList<SearchRequest>();
        SearchRequest requests = new SearchRequest();

        LinkedList<EntityType> entityTypesList = new LinkedList<EntityType>();
        entityTypesList.add(EntityType.DRIVE_ITEM);
        requests.entityTypes = entityTypesList;

        LinkedList<SortProperty> sortProperties = new LinkedList<>();
        SortProperty sort = new SortProperty();
        sort.name = "lastModifiedDateTime";
        sort.isDescending = true;
        sortProperties.add(sort);

        SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery();
        query.queryString = fileName;
        requests.query = query;
        requests.sortProperties = sortProperties;
        requests.size = 1;

        requestsList.add(requests);

        SearchEntityQueryParameterSet sqp = SearchEntityQueryParameterSet
                .newBuilder()
                .withRequests(requestsList)
                .build();

        SearchEntityQueryCollectionPage searchResult = graphClient.search().query(sqp)
                .buildRequest()
                .post();

        DriveItem fileResult = null;
        for (SearchResponse searchResponse : searchResult.getCurrentPage()) {
            if (searchResponse.hitsContainers != null) {
                for (SearchHitsContainer searchHitsContainer : searchResponse.hitsContainers) {
                    if (searchHitsContainer.hits != null) {
                        for (SearchHit searchHit : searchHitsContainer.hits) {
                            fileResult = (DriveItem) searchHit.resource;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<DriveItem> items = null;
        DriveItemRequestBuilder destination = null;

        DriveRequestBuilder driverReq = graphClient.sites(SharePointCopierConfig.SITE_ID).drive();
        DriveItemRequestBuilder driverRootReq = driverReq.root();

        destination = driverRootReq.itemWithPath(destinationPath);

        ItemReference parentReference = new ItemReference();
        parentReference.driveId = driverReq.buildRequest().get().id;
        parentReference.id = destination.buildRequest().get().id;

        if (fileResult != null) {
                graphClient.me().drive().items(fileResult.id).copy(
                DriveItemCopyParameterSet
                        .newBuilder()
                        .withName(fileName)
                        .withParentReference(parentReference)
                        .build())
                    .buildRequest()
                    .post();
        }

        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long timeSeconds = (timeEnd-timeStart);
        return fileName + " Copy Successful in "+timeSeconds+" ms";
    }catch (GraphServiceException exception){
        logger.error(exception.getServiceError().code+" "+exception.getMessage());
        return "Error Copying "+exception.getMessage();
    }

}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, my problem, is that i was basically i was triying to copy form the destination as a base.

What i needed to do was change my copy command, by doing the following

```
                graphClient.drives(fileResult.parentReference.driveId).items(fileResult.id).copy(
                            DriveItemCopyParameterSet
                                    .newBuilder()
                                    .withName(fileName)
                                    .withParentReference(parentReference)
                                    .build())
                    .buildRequest()
                    .post();
```

By doing it like this i was taking the drive where i found the file as a source, and from there on i called the copy to the destination.